# How can I use packery with polymer elements?

Tags: polymer, packery

I've been searching for hours now on how to use packery in combination with polymer elements. What I want to achieve is an element that is a content list, with in it an element that's the content item. I want to content items to be "packaried".

To clarify:

```
<packery-element>
<template repeat="{{item in items}}">
<content-item class="item"></content-item>
</template>
</packery-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We created our own custom element, that also uses bin-packing algorithm:
[`<juicy-tile-list>`](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-tile-list): http://juicy.github.io/juicy-tile-list/

Then, all you need is:

```
<link rel="import" href="../juicy-tile-list/dist/juicy-tile-list.html">
...
<juicy-tile-list>
  <div>Some</div>
  <div>tiles</div>
  <section>here</section>
</juicy-tile-list>
```

We are pretty focused on development of this one, so in case of any problem please fill [GH issue](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-tile-list/issues?state=open). We'll be more than thankful for any feedback.

We extended it with couple of [additional features](https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-tile-list#features), like:

- pririties items,
- grouping into virtual, nested containers,
- alignment in different orientations/directions,
- dynamically changing size,
- auto adjusting container sizes,
- gap/gutter/cell-spacing between tiles,
- adapting to window size changes.

And created two side components:

- [`<juicy-tile-grid>`](http://juicy.github.io/juicy-tile-grid/) - to use adaptive features of native CSS Grid Layout,
- [`<juicy-tile-editor>`](http://juicy.github.io/juicy-tile-grid/) to make fiddling with tiles easier.

We also have plan to separate core Masonry/Packery like behavior from all additional features for cleaner and faster code, for those that don't need that.

Comment: Thanks! But what I want to do is to fill the juicy tile list with a template repeat > with it in an element content-item.

Comment: @kingflurkel is it a specific `custom-item` element?
`<juicy-tile-list><template repeat="{{list}}"><custom-item>{{desc}}/custom-item></template></juicy-tile-list>`
 Works for me like charm. Do you want me to post it as a separate demo on gh-pages?

Currently we have an example with custom element as a tile here: http://juicy.github.io/juicy-tile-list/examples/nested.html (another `<juicy-tile-list>` is this element ;) )

Comment: I would love to see an example with <template repeat><custom-element></custom-element></template>

Comment: Is that http://juicy.github.io/juicy-tile-list/examples/other/templateRepeatCustomItem.html what you need?

Comment: Here is example that shows how to use `juicy-tile-list` inside another custom element: http://juicy.github.io/juicy-tile-list/examples/other/templateRepeatCustomItem.html

Comment: With the new version of juicy list everything worked fine out of the box. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that could be a trivial `packery-element.html` import:

```
  <script src="http://packery.metafizzy.co/packery.pkgd.js"></script>

  <polymer-element name="packery-element" block>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        domReady: function() {
          this.packery = new Packery(this, {
            itemSelector: '*',
            gutter: 10
          });
        }
      });
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
```

Live http://jsbin.com/qoqati/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for this! But what if the divs are other polymer elements?

Comment: Doesn't generally matter what the child elements are. http://jsbin.com/qoqati/4/edit